# SELECT NULL in OpenEdge Query

Tags: openedge

I would like to be able to `SELECT` a NULL value in my `SELECT` list so I can use it later in a UNION (for example). When I try `SELECT NULL AS my_null_value FROM some_table` it gives me a syntax error. I can work around it by doing the following.

```
    SELECT CASE WHEN 1=1 THEN NULL END AS my_null_value
    FROM some_table
```

Is there a cleaner way to accomplish this? I feel like I have done this in less characters and in a simpler manner in the past than using a `CASE` statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ending up finding it.

A simpler (or more shorthand) way to accomplish this is to use the following:

```
    SELECT NULLIF(0,0) AS my_null_value
    FROM some_table
```